# How to create a function in postgresql that accepts array of parameters and returns a table

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-8.3

Here is how my function is looks:

```
create or replace function datafabric.test(psi_codes text[])
returns table (asset character varying (255), parent_asset character varying (255))
as
$$
select asset, parent_asset 
from americas.asset a
left join americas.prod_int p on a.row_id = p.row_id
where root_asset_id in (select root_asset_id from americas.asset where p.name =  ANY($1))
$$ LANGUAGE 'SQL' VOLATILE;
```

However, the problem is that I am getting this

> ERROR: function datafabric.test() does not exist SQL state: 42883 DURING the CREATION OF THE FUNCTION.

Please note that this function works. However, I want to output the results on pgadmin screen. I am not able to do that now.

Please help. I am using postgresql 8.3 version.

Comment: What's the intention of the `alter function`? It's invalid syntax. And please don't put the language name in single quotes - it's an identifier.

Comment: no intention. I added here by mistake. Removing it.

Comment: You are right, thanks. I removed single quotes from language. It now works, but here is what I get now. ERROR: query has no destination for result data
SQL state: 42601

Comment: I want to print the results in pgadmin client..similar to how a select statment would output..

Comment: Why the [outdated version 8.3](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)? Your question is inconclusive; not enough information. Please table-qualify all columns in your query or provide table definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL 8.3 doesn't support RETURNS TABLE for functions. You also have to specify the language of a function without the quotes.

You can achieve a similar behaviour through the following:

```
create or replace function 
       datafabric.test(psi_codes text[],
                       OUT asset character varying (255),
                       OUT parent_asset character varying (255))
       RETURNS SETOF RECORD as $$
select asset, parent_asset 
from americas.asset a
left join americas.prod_int p on a.row_id = p.row_id
where root_asset_id in (select root_asset_id from americas.asset where p.name =  ANY($1))
$$ LANGUAGE SQL VOLATILE;
```